# How to clean up text data in a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I am playing around with some banking information and I have a csv file of all my transactions. I have opened it up as a dataframe and it looks something like this:

[banking.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSI3W.png)

my as you can see in the 2nd column, there is a whole bunch of text that I do not need, all I am interested in is the store name which typically comes at the end.

I have managed to get rid of the part that says 'Point of sale - INTERAC RETAIL PURCHASE'
by using

> checking['POS'] = checking['POS'].str.replace('Point of Sale - Interac RETAIL PURCHASE', '')

my issue now comes when I try to delete the numbers that comes after that, just before the store names. I wanted to do something similar to above but the numbers are all unique so I am not sure how I can do this. 
thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a replace with Regular expressions:

```
import re    
checking['POS'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r"Point of Sale - Interac RETAIL PURCHASE \d+", "", x))
```

`\d+` = "one or more numbers".

So that will only work if there are only numbers between the text and the store name.

The `.replace` unfortunately does not allow regular expressions thats why you have to use the `re` module.

Comment: @T0r0nt0 you're welcome. If you liked the anwer you could also upvote it.

Comment: I did upvote it but it says that it will not show up because I have less than 15 reputation :( I also have a follow up question similar to this answer. some of my columns also have a store number after the store name (so similar situation but on the other end of the string). for example dollarama # 218. to get rid of the #218 I tried to do `df.apply(lambda x: x.rstrip('#\d+')` this code runs without any errors but it does not change anything in the dataset. do you know why this may be the case?

Comment: The problem is, that `rstrip` does not accept regular expressions as well. To extract a part of the text you could use `re.search` like: `re.search('Point of Sale - Interac RETAIL PURCHASE \d+ (.*) \d+', x).group(1)`. But be aware that this has no error handling. So if the text does not match the regular expression the `group(1)` would crash.